# A better way to deserialize JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am posting to an API that may return either 1 of the following 2 formats of JSON strings:

```
{
"MessageType": 6,
"Message": "Unable to SAVE new record. Invalid posted data."
}
```

or

```
{
"Model": {
    "Id": "1-6Q0RZ9",
    ...

         },   
"ResponseResult": {
    "MessageType": 10,
    "Message": "Successfully saved, Record Id = 1-6Q0RZ9"
                  }
}
```

I need to retrieve the results from MessageType and have tried every if condition I can think of to read the results, because the syntax or retrieving the key:value is different for each JSON string, and there are no other flags to trigger one or the other. So the code I used is:

```
string result = eml.PostData("API/Save", dataJSON.ToString());
var returnresult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(result);
try {
  var responseresults = returnresult["ResponseResult"];
  rr = responseresults["MessageType"];
  rrtxt = responseresults["Message"];
} catch (Exception ex) {
  rr = returnresult["MessageType"];
  rrtxt = returnresult["Message"];
}
```

Which works great. If there is a valid Db post it returns the second JSON which is parsed correctly by the TRY statement, if not it throws a "key not found" error and parses the returned string in the CATCH statement (the first JSON example). Obviously this is horrible code but I cannot think of another way to do this, and I was wondering if anyone had suggestions? (please?)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I strongly recommend [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: I had similar issues with JSON.Net, there is no way to know which string you are going to get until you have it in my case.

Comment: While JSON.Net will have the same issues, it performs much better than the JSON parser you're using.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I still need to solve the problem...

Comment: @RickBailly does not the solution below work for you?

Comment: just tried this morning, looks like it's close but for my lack of coding skills. Please see below.

Answer (score 1):

How about deserializing the response to an object with all of the properties on each return type and then just checking the values?

```
public class ReturnObject
{
     public YourModel Model {get;set;}
     public ResultObject ResponseResult {get;set;}
     public int? MessageType {get;set;}
     public string Message {get;set;}
}


string result = eml.PostData("API/Save", dataJSON.ToString());
var returnresult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ReturnObject>(result);
{
  if(returnresult.MessageType.HasValue)
  {
     var messageType = returnResult.MessageType.Value;
     etc etc.
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm not quite sure what should be referenced by public YourModel Model {get;set;} or ResultObject ResponseResult. With them I get type or namespace not found, without them I get a MessageType of 0 (the API only returns results of 1 through 17). Pardon my ignorance, please advise.

Comment: you would need to know their data structure as well and create classes for them.

Comment: forgot to mention I set the return integer to zero initially, so the if statement apparently doesnt return true

Comment: On further testing it appears that the if statement doesnt even hit the breakpoint I set at it if it returns the second JSON string, but the API log show a successful submission. It currently DOES work when the first json string is returned.

Comment: Another solution would be to have your messagetype be an enum type with the first enum member being `None` and you could check for a messagetype by saying something like `if(returnresult.MessageType != MessageType.None)` etc etc.  A none existent enum member will get serialized to the `zero` value. which is the first member or your enum usually.

Comment: can you add a string representation  of both responses back from the api to your question?

Comment: That would be the first 2 strings shown in the original question, either it's a MessageType or a Model, ResponseResult, MessageType. And you dont know which until you get it back. I may try testing for one of the required values in the Model, but that just looks messy to me.

Comment: Sorry :) .  Do  you mind telling me what the api is you're coding against?

Comment: I dont mind, I'm just not sure I understand the question. It's built in C# based on MVC 4 and run locally. I have no input or control over what I get back, I'm given a sample JSON string and told "match that"

Comment: It looks like your call to `API/Save` is a local call to your own application which means you should have access to what that api method is returning to you.  Why don't you modify what that method returns to have a normalized object with a success property?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35302/discussion-between-rick-bailly-and-bluetoft)